# Azure functions - Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=a8867dc8-3551-4396-84a4-ff55e86fd0f6, Duration=15ms)

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I recently upgraded my dotnet project version from 3.1 to 6.0 and after the upgrade, getting below error in azure functions

[image]

And for Azure function my C# code looks like this

```
[FunctionName("AuditManagerTopic")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(Constants.ServiceBusName.AuditTopic, Subscription, Connection = Constants.ConnectionString.ServiceBus)] Message message, ILogger logger)
    {
        try
        {
            _ = logger;
            if (message == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));

            var activity = message.Body.DecompressGZip().FromBytes<ActivityAudit>();

            //TODO: Clean this logic up when full resolution of BUG 52019
            activity.Audit ??= activity.Payment;

            var auditManager = ManagerFactory.Create<IAuditManager>();

            await auditManager.Process(activity).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception.");
            throw;
        }
        
    }
```

Even after changing AzureFunctionsVersion from V3 to V4, no luck.

local.settings.json

`{ "IsEncrypted": false, "Values": { "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet", "ConnectionStrings:ServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb://cde-sbn-cus-mstysync-01.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "ConnectionStrings:shipmentDomainServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb://cde-sbn-cus-shipment-01.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=masteryDataSync;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" } }`

My azure libraries versions are below

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.7.0" />
```

Do I need to downgrade or upgrade any above azure libraries or any suggestions please where could be the problem

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the NullReferenceException? That would really help you figure this out

Comment: Without that, my best guess would be the Dependency Injection has changed in .net-6.0 so `ManagerFactory` is null

Comment: yes, that null exception is from azure functions

Comment: WARNING!!! You are including a secret to your service bus in the question, I advise you to delete that and regenerate a new one

Comment: after upgrading to net6.0 version the message body is coming as null. Not sure why this is happening

Comment: Are you running *in-process* or *isolated*? Azure Functions introduced the *isolated* hosting model around 6.0 and it makes a difference to how the trigger bindings work. [Differences between in-process and isolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-in-process-differences)

Comment: I don't think the latest version supports the type "Message" anymore. I compiles but won't work.  Try to change the message type to string (string message rather than Message message) and get the latest libs: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus

Comment: Glad I could help, @Sudhakar Chitlam. Look like at some point it was still accepting the "Message" type (new class  serviceBusReceivedMessage) but now the message comes as "string. Will add some more detail in the answer space to add some screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Look like the most recent version of ServiceBusTrigger does not receive the message as an object from Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.

Checking the documentation and some blogs around, at some point it was able to receive as ServiceBusReceivedMessage
[image]

Back on 2.x was "Message"
[image]

But the most recent version of "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" (In Process) or "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" (Isolated) **along** with the **most recent** version of "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" will only accept those types:

[image]

I couldn't find any official documentation confirming past version but found a few blogs:

[image]

So, case you are upgrading or find a blog suggesting to use Message or ServiceBusReceivedMessage and you receive null or "object not a reference", replace ServiceBusReceivedMessage or Message with "string"

or

This worked with some earlier version of Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus:

[image]

I had to remove the zure.Messaging.ServiceBus from the project file
[image]

this somehow compiles and loads a version of Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus that enables ServiceBusReceivedMessage.

[image]